# How to use @Action in Mobx + reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am confused on how to use @action in my code.

```
class Items {

  @observable items= [];

  @action addItem() {
    let newItem= new Item();
    items.push(newItem);
  }
}

@observer
class ItemPage extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    const {addItem} = this.props.store;
    return (
      <div className="items">
        <input type="button" value="add" onClick={addItem}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const store = new Items();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that you alter `this.items` and not just `items`. You also need to bind either the action with `action.bound` or create a bound handler in the component:

```
class Items {
  @observable items= [];

  @action.bound
  addItem() {
    let newItem = new Item();
    this.items.push(newItem);
  }
}

@observer
class ItemPage extends Component {
  render() {
    const { addItem } = this.props.store;
    return (
      <div className="items">
        <input type="button" value="add" onClick={addItem}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const store = new Items();
```

Or:

```
class Items {
  @observable items= [];

  @action
  addItem() {
    let newItem = new Item();
    this.items.push(newItem);
  }
}

@observer
class ItemPage extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.store.addItem();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="items">
        <input type="button" value="add" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const store = new Items();
```

Comment: Is @action.bound the more recommended way? Seems like duplicating a method for no real gain if you don't use it?

Comment: @chobo2 It really just comes down to preference. I personally tend to create handlers on my components, if I e.g. need to do more than just call the action later, so I usually go with option two.

Comment: Any reason why, as it just sort of looks like bit more work but not seeing real any gain. I also seen a 3rd option where they put @action in the component itself.

Comment: @Tholle beautifully explained! It was so clear, I couldn't find any explanation as simple as this. Thank you!